# php mix with javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I'd like to mix php with javascript 
Here is my code:

```
<?php
function sayHi(){


 echo 'Good Morning';

}
echo 'hello';
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
?>



<script>
    document.write('bingo');
    <?php
  sayHi();
 }
 ?>

</script>
```

It stopped working when it finished echo 'hello'; 
How can I make it work fine?
could you please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do?

The code you have prints as..

```
<script>
    document.write('bingo');
    Good Morning
</script>
```

The reason it broke is because Javascript is very touchy and Good Morning isn't valid javascript.

If you want to print "good morning" you have to do this.

```
<script>
    document.write('<?php sayHi(); ?>');
</script>
```

Which prints as

```
<script>
    document.write('Good Morning');
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your sayHi() function outputs something invalid inside a `<script>` tag, so it won't work...